# wx.AcceleratorEntry with non alphanumerical characters

Tags: wxpython

Is it possible to use "wx.AcceleratorEntry" whit non alphanumeric characters? If yes what I'm missing?

I've checked the documentation for wx.MenuItem.SetItemLabel which says "The accelerator may be any alphanumeric character" but if I try to set the accelerator to some other character for example (, comma) (. dot) (ì i with grave accent) they are accepted and appear in the menu but only the comma works when the keys combination are pressed.

Here an example with (python 2.7) and (wxPython 4.0.1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx


class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    """Example frame with a simple menu for accelerators test."""

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Accelerators test")

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        decoded_menu = wx.Menu()
        first_menu_item = decoded_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "First\tCtrl+a", "First menu")
        second_menu_item = decoded_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Second\tCtrl+.", "Second menu")
        menu_bar.Append(decoded_menu, "&Decoded")

        explicit_menu = wx.Menu()
        third_menu_item = explicit_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Third", "Third menu")
        third_menu_item.SetAccel(wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord(",")))
        fourth_menu_item = explicit_menu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Fourth", "Fourth menu")
        fourth_menu_item.SetAccel(wx.AcceleratorEntry(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord(u"ì")))
        menu_bar.Append(explicit_menu, "&Explicit")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_first, first_menu_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_second, second_menu_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_third, third_menu_item)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_fourth, fourth_menu_item)

    def on_first(self, event):
        """First button event handler."""

        print 'First'

    def on_second(self, event):
        """Second button event handler."""

        print 'Second'

    def on_third(self, event):
        """Third button event handler."""

        print 'Third'

    def on_fourth(self, event):
        """Third button event handler."""

        print 'Fourth'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

- CTRL+A of course works
- CTRL+. does not work
- CTRL+, works
- CTRL+ì does not work

I do not understand what is wrong.